# Using a terminology in Symfony's translation component - especially with validation messages

Tags: symfony

I know and understood how to translate validation messages in Symfony 2.

Just to repeat it from the official documentation:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
     /**
      * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "author.name.not_blank")
      */
      public $name;
}
```

And I would set up a translation file/key for it like:

```
 <!-- validators.en.xlf -->
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
     <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
         <body>
             <trans-unit id="1">
                 <source>author.name.not_blank</source>
                 <target>Please enter an author name.</target>
             </trans-unit>
         </body>
     </file>
</xliff>
```

This works perfectly fine, but in my case I'd heavily need some terminology to use, so e.g. in the example case above have a separate translation for 'author', because if my 'author' occurs in many validation messages, I'd need to change every occurrence of 'author' as soon as it's not 'author' anymore but e.g. 'creator'.

Is there any change to have something like:

```
 <target>Please enter an %author% name.</target>
```

With an additional translation like:

```
 <!-- validators.en.xlf -->
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
     <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
         <body>
             <trans-unit id="2">
                 <source>author</source>
                 <target>creator</target>
             </trans-unit>
         </body>
     </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a bad idea IMO, because it makes it much harder to write translation messages when using placeholders which are themselves translations. And I can give you a simple example where it breaks: just translate your messages above in French.

- `Merci d'entrer un nom d'auteur`
- `Merci d'entrer un nom de créateur`

As you see, renaming `author` to `creator` does not only involve changing this word, but also other words in the message (thinking about the English version only is what leads to such mistake, as English is much simpler in this regard). So if you follow your suggestion, you will be unable to translate your app in most languages.

Comment: I agree with you. Even in my example that's the case: 'an author' would become 'an creator' which is not correct English, 'a creator' would be correct. But still, aware of this issue, it would help a lot, especially in those short annotated validation messages.